# Rails applications gives 400 error when request is sent to an end point giving "Reloading does not reboot the application"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, port, autoload, datadog

Application is using datadog, initially it was giving 404 not found although in logs I could see that it was giving Datadog tracer configuration, failed to establish TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:8126 ,Datadog::Transport::InternalRrrorResponse. Please not the application is connected to test database and I am using docker.

Since I did not need datadog locally, I commented that out and rebuild it and started container again but then it was not giving datadog error but the error mentioned below

reloading does not reboot the application, and therefore code executed during initialization does not run again. sp if you reload logger for example the expected changes wont be reflected int hat stale class object `config.autoloader` is set to `classic`. These autoload constant would have been unloaded if `config.autoloader` had been set to `:zeitwerk`Please, check the "Autoloading and Reloading Constants" guide for solutions.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I am using postman to send a simple GET request on an end point that is intended for mobile apps.

Comment: That message is a warning. It tells you that reloading a certain constant won't have an effect in whatever it was used for during initialization. I'd bet it is unrelated to the 400.

Comment: To give more information, that warning is issued when the application boots. It is unrelated to the web request. If you run `bin/rails runner 1` you'll see the warning too. You need to find logs for the 400 itself.

Comment: May be I am missing out some headers in postman request, that is triggering 400 then?

Comment: I believe you should concentrate on finding the logs of the application they probably will help you figure out what's wrong.